# Unable to obtain peer certificate using HTTParty

Tags: ruby, httparty

I am on a MacBook (macOS 10.14.3) with OpenSSL 1.1.1b (installed via Homebrew), ruby 2.6.0 (installed via rvm), and HTTParty 0.16.4 (installed via gem/bundler). According to [this example](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/examples/peer_cert.rb), it should be possible to download a website's peer certificate. However, when I attempt this on my machine it fails:

```rb
require "httparty"

peer_cert = nil

HTTParty.get("https://www.example.com") do |fragment|
  peer_cert ||= fragment.connection.peer_cert
end

p peer_cert
```

With the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    28: from tmp/test.rb:5:in `<main>'
    27: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/httparty-0.16.4/lib/httparty.rb:623:in `get'
    26: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/httparty-0.16.4/lib/httparty.rb:491:in `get'
    25: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/httparty-0.16.4/lib/httparty.rb:573:in `perform_request'
    24: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/httparty-0.16.4/lib/httparty/request.rb:146:in `perform'
    23: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1470:in `request'
    22: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:920:in `start'
    21: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1472:in `block in request'
    20: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1479:in `request'
    19: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1517:in `transport_request'
    18: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:165:in `reading_body'
    17: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1518:in `block in transport_request'
    16: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/httparty-0.16.4/lib/httparty/request.rb:150:in `block in perform'
    15: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:204:in `read_body'
    14: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:283:in `read_body_0'
    13: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:264:in `inflater'
    12: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:293:in `block in read_body_0'
    11: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:405:in `read'
    10: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:163:in `read'
     9: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:488:in `<<'
     8: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:497:in `call_block'
     7: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:382:in `block in inflate_adapter'
     6: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:382:in `inflate'
     5: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:384:in `block (2 levels) in inflate_adapter'
     4: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:488:in `<<'
     3: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:497:in `call_block'
     2: from /Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/httparty-0.16.4/lib/httparty/request.rb:152:in `block (2 levels) in perform'
     1: from tmp/test.rb:6:in `block in <main>'
/Users/nicholas.chambers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/delegate.rb:87:in `method_missing': undefined method `connection' for #<HTTParty::FragmentWithResponse:0x00007f9382035440> (NoMethodError)
```

I've looked through open issues in the repository, and did some googling, but nothing came up. I'm currently at a loss. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Update:
Although I'd like to know why HTTParty doesn't work, [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601260/using-ruby-openssl-to-download-and-read-certificates) does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0.16.4` does not have a `connection` [Source](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/v0.16.4/lib/httparty/fragment_with_response.rb)

the "example" you are referring to corresponds with additional changes

- https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/commit/24106eef272953f3190db9115dc5ac5f6aa1600e#diff-580cbdf9b30c3492eaffdfa72a97aa58
- https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/commit/9b5f5012ac7bb401b376c9e62179f10099f709d8

So it appears that you would need to install directly from github to have access to this feature or wait until the next version is released.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep that in mind. I found a workaround using `OpenSSL` and `socket`, so I'll just use that in the meantime.